# How to increase/decrease decibels of recorded audio tracks with FFmpeg?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I'm using the following command to record the desktop with FFmpeg, as well as two audio sources:

- "virtual-audio-capturer"
- "Microphone (Logitech USB Headset)"

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -i desktop -f dshow -i audio="virtual-audio-capturer"
-f dshow -i audio="Microphone (Logitech USB Headset)"
-filter_complex amix=inputs=2:duration=longest output.mp4
```

How can I increase the volume of "virtual-audio-capturer" by 10 decibels and decrease the volume of "Microphone (Logitech USB Headset)" by 10 decibels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FFmpeg doesn't support increase/decrease the volume by decibels.
The closest solution is using `-show_audio_device_dialog true`, `-audio_device_save` and `-audio_device_load` as described [here](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#Options-5).

---

Usage example:

Execute FFmpeg with `-show_audio_device_dialog true` and `-audio_device_save` with null output:

`ffmpeg -f dshow -show_audio_device_dialog true -audio_device_save audio_profile.txt -i audio="Microphone (Logitech USB Headset)" -t 0.1 -f null -`

A dialog box with few options is opened (if supported by the device):
[image]
Note that different devices may have different options.

Select the volume of the microphone and press OK (requires some trial and error).
The configuration is stored to `audio_profile.txt` file.

---

For loading the selected configuration, use `-audio_device_load`.
Example:

`ffmpeg -y -f dshow -audio_device_load audio_profile.txt -i audio="Microphone (Logitech USB Headset)" test.mp3`

Comment: This is good but how do I handle changing the volume on my two sources, audio="virtual-audio-capturer" and audio="Microphone (Logitech USB Headset)"?

Comment: Try to create two profiles, and use something like `ffmpeg -f gdigrab -i desktop -f dshow -audio_device_load audio_profile1.txt -i audio="virtual-audio-capturer" -f dshow -audio_device_load audio_profile2.txt -i audio="Microphone (Logitech USB Headset)" -filter_complex amix=inputs=2:duration=longest output.mp4`.It's not going to work with `virtual-audio-capturer` device, because the virtual device doesn't support the dialog box. Consider using [volume filer](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioVolume) for the virtual device.